# NoReverseMatch: with arguments '(u'',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.in Django Admin

Tags: django, exception, django-admin

**I found a better error message (see below).**

I have a model called App in core/models.py. The error occurs when trying to access a specific app object in django admin. Even on an empty database (after syncdb) with a single app object.

Seems core_app_history is something django generated. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the exception:

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/core/app/251/
Reverse for 'core_app_history' with arguments '(u'',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://weblocal:8001/admin/core/app/251/
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'core_app_history' with arguments '(u'',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
Exception Location: /opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 426
Python Executable:  /opt/virtenvs/django_slice/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/opt/src/slicephone/cloud',
'/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
'/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
'/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg',
'/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/lib/python2.7',
'/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 11 Oct 2013 22:06:43 +0000
```

And it occurs in /django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html

```
32      <li><a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'history' original.pk|admin_urlquote %}" class="historylink">{% trans "History" %}</a></li>
```

Here is the (possible) relevant urls:

```
/admin/core/app/    HANDLER: changelist_view
/admin/core/app/add/    HANDLER: add_view
/admin/core/app/(.+)/history/   HANDLER: history_view
/admin/core/app/(.+)/delete/    HANDLER: delete_view
/admin/core/app/(.+)/   HANDLER: change_view
```

Comment: Do all your other views work?

Comment: Show your `views` and `urls` of that app.

Comment: @AryehLeibTaurog Yes, all other views and the admin interface works fine.

Comment: @sachitad Sorry, I don't want to show all of our urls here.

Comment: Not all `url` and `view` of the error.

Comment: @sachitad Appended the routes to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be you have a view referenced somewhere in your urlconf which can't be imported, which would cause `reverse` to fail.  Try reversing a different view from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by having an entry with an empty primary key, which could happen if your model has a field like

```
id = models.CharField(blank=True, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to comment on this as I had EXACTLY the same issue and this was the only link I could find that pointed me in the right direction. Actually it didn't point me in the right direction but at least it made me feel less alone :)

Note my code did work sometimes. In fact my wrong code is still working happily on a production server.

My problem was in admin I had overridden my render_change_form. When I called the super method instead of doing

```
return super(ReceiptAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

I had inadvertently done

```
return super(ReceiptAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, args, kwargs)
```

I find this out when I stepped through the code and noticed what my parent method was being passed didn't look right. It mystifies me why it works sometimes. This incorrect call was copied and pasted from some other code which is also failing locally but not on live.

Anyway, there if any use for anybody else.